# Could someone clarify the code snippet

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

```
$("#gameCanvas").mousedown(function(e) {
    var canvasPosition = $(this).offset();
    var mouseX = e.layerX || 0;
    var mouseY = e.layerY || 0;
}
```

From what I understand. the `e.layerX` and `e.layerY` will give me the cursor coordinates relative to the canvas window.

What would the `canvasPosition = $(this).offset();` do?

When I look at the rest of the block of code (didn't want to paste it all, there's too much) `canvasPosition` is not used. What would I use it for? Basically the code allows me to move a circle, drawn on the canvas, around using the mouse.

Comment: Well, if the variable isn't used anywhere else inside the function, it is probably a leftover from a previous edit which was using it...

Comment: have you read the jquery documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/offset/) the jQuery offset function give the position of an element.

So, in this case, it will return an object containing the position of the canvas, in pixel, relative to the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this code snippet, the portion `var canvasPosition = $(this).offset();` is doing nothing. Surely leftover. Coder might have thought of using canvas position to identify locaiton of mouse pointer relative to canvas.